# Extend validation.js and validate single elements

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

Is it possible in Magento to extend validation.js to add the ability to validate single elements as opposed to complete forms.

If it is not possible what is the most unobtrusive way of customizing the validation.js script

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based more on the detail provided in the comment to Francesco than the initial question - If validation is required validation for individual form elements onblur then you need to set the 'immediate' property of the Validation object to true like so...

```
Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
```

This will cause validation to occur if an elements value has been changed **and** it looses focus.

I take it this is a site wide change - so I would normally place code such as this my themes js file but alternatively you can also place it in a template (obviously before your form object gets initialised) by enclosing it in script tags i.e..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I am working on some custom validation right now and thought it would be tricky to do this, but one simple line of code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CMS Block with a content like below, and add a Widget setting the Checkout page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('.validate-michael-jackson').first().observe('blur', function(elem){
        if (elem.value == 'Michael Jackson') {
            alert('Come on baby! Are you really Michael Jackson?');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this : 
[Link](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Inchoo+%28Magento%2C+Wordpress%2C+Online+Marketing%2C+iPhone+development+%40+Inchoo%29)

By what I remember you can easly add a new validation in your .phtml files by extending validation.js class

Comment: Ideally validation on individual form elements. I would like this to facilitate validation on element blur for when user clicks or tabs from input

Comment: sorry by extending validation I understood you mean to add new validation case ... 
What are you looking for is another stuff.